# Given a DI-Graph. Check if exists path from (u,v) or (v,u) for all pairs of nodes

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

If i have a Di-Graph. How to check if all pairs (u,v) of nodes of this graph are related ?
**Relation** means that there is a connection between [u,v] or [v,u].

Here is a example:
In this image, the left most graph has a relation between all pairs. The right-one not;

[image: Example]

To solve this problem i've tried BFS from the original given graph and its reversed graph.
We have a related graph if and only if all nodes are visited with the two bfs.
Else the graph isn't related.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vii;

void DFS(bool *vst,vii &G,int ini){

    queue<int> q;
    q.push(ini);

    int cur;
    while(!q.empty()){
        cur = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if(vst[cur])
            continue;

        vst[cur] = true;

        vi &adj = G[cur];
        for (vi::iterator it = adj.begin(); it != adj.end(); ++it)
            q.push(*it);
    }
}

int main(void){
    //N is the number of Nodes and M is the number of Edges
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    vii G(n+1); //graph
    vii R(n+1);//reversed graph

    //read and fill both graphs
    for (int i = 0,u,v; i < m; ++i) {
        scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
        G[u].push_back(v);
        R[v].push_back(u);
    }

    //get some node with outdegree and indegree > 0
    int S = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        if(G[i].size() > 0  && R[i].size() > 0){
            S = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    bool vst1[n+1];
    bool vst2[n+1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        vst1[i] = vst2[i] = false;


    if(S != -1){
        DFS(vst1, G, S);
        DFS(vst2, R, S);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        if((vst1[i] || vst2[i]) == false){
            i = -1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == n+1)
        puts("All pairs related");
    else
        puts("All pairs not-related");
}
```

But this solution is wrong in 30% of the test-cases; This is a contest problem and i don't have access to the input =(

What am I doing wrong ?

**Input description**:

> The first line has two integers **N** and **M** (1 ≤ N,M ≤ 100000) and the next **M** lines has two integers **U** and **V** (1 ≤ U,V ≤ N).
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>   3 3
>   1 3
>   2 3
>   3 1
>
> **Sample Input 2**
>   3 2
>   1 3
>   2 3
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>   All pairs related
>
> **Sample Output 2**
>   All pairs not-related

Comment: What if there is some path that requires a mix of forward and backward travel?

Comment: @Felipe This is fairly simple algorithm.But I have implemented it in Java.

Comment: @Sumeet can you explain me ? My approach is the right one or it does not solve the problem ?

Comment: @Sumeet i know java =)

Comment: @Felipe Do you want me to explain algo or code or should I do both.

Comment: @Sumeet if you give me only a description of the algorithm is enough. I don't want to bother you with a implementation =)

Comment: @Felipe Gave explanation, Feel free for any queries.

Comment: @Felipe updated my answer.Please inform,if you find an example for which it fails. Hopefully it will not.

Answer (score 2):

So, This is can be easily checked using any graph traversal BFS or DFS.

I am assuming this definition.

```
A directed graph is connected if for all pairs (u,v), there exists a directed path from u 
to v OR there exists a directed path from v to u.
```

First check if the graph is Strongly connected, if yes then definitely the graph the graph is connected, if not proceed as following:

Begin graph traversal from any source vertex S,where S must have both indegree and outdegree>0, if we do not have any vertex of such type, then graph is not connected(reason in the end).

Now mark all the vertices which are visited to be elements of set S1.

Then reverse the graph and again begin the graph traversal from same source vertex S.

Again mark all the vertices visited to be elements of set S2.

The graph is connected if and only if

```
S1 U S2 = V
```

Proof By Contradiction.

Let us assume the above algorithm to be wrong and say the graph is connected even if

```
S1 U S2 is proper subset of V.
```

But if S1 U S2 is a proper subset of V, there must be a vertex v,which remained untouched in both traversals,which means the following:

```
There is no path from v to S and also from S to v.
```

Hence Contradiction,therefore our initial assumption is wrong, and in the case where **S1 U S2 is a proper subset of V**, the graph cannot be connected.

Now take any pair of vertices (u,v).

Case 1:

```
S1 and S2 both contained u and v, which means that there is a directed path
from u to v and also from v to u.
```

Case 2:

```
u and v are in different sets,still there exists a path from u to v OR from
v to u.
```

Case 3:

```
Both u and v are in same set.
```

Consider the diagram:[image]

Say we begin our first traversal from X ,then we have:

```
S1={X,Y,e}

S2={X}
```

and clearly S1 U S2 = V, but there is no path for pair (Y,e) and **this is the reason why source vertex must have both indegree and outdegree > 0 which clearly X does not have** and indeed none of vertices satisfy this condition and hence the graph is not connected.

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem =( . Because this algorithm checks if there is a path to u,v **and** v,u for all pairs of a graph. I want a algorithm that checks if there is a path from u,v **or** v,u for all pairs.

Comment: @Felipe So sorry, never saw the or, will update my answer.

Comment: No problem. Thx for helping me. You don't need to apologize =)

Comment: I've tried implement it but still the same wrong percentage. Wrong in 30% of test-cases;

Comment: This approach does not work for all cases. E.g. Consider a graph with 4 nodes. A, B, C and D. There are three edges A->B, A->C and D->A. Given algorithm considers this to be connected while there is no path between B and C.